# primefaces : show message growl if there isn´t a selected item, else open dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, growl

I want to check the following: 
I have a dataTable, but selected a row and I click the edit button, then you must leave a message, otherwise open a popup so that the user can change the value

**my button is:**

```
 <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.Edit}" id="editBotonFormula" icon="ui-icon-pencil" update=":growl" oncomplete="handleSubmit(args,'OprEditarFormulaDialog');" actionListener="#{oprFormulaMedicaController.validarSeleccionado}"/>
```

**My Managed bean method is:**

```
public void validarSeleccionado(){

    if (selected != null) {

        System.out.println(" hay dato seleeccionado en formulaMedica" + selected);
   //open popup to edit Dialogvar.Show;


    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No hay dato seleccionado " + selected);
        //Show open error message (growl) and not open popup JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("NoHayFilaSeleccionada"));
    }
}
```

My question is : 
How can I open the dialog (popup)if the row is selected ?????

thanks

Comment: I found the following :                                        if (selected != null) {

            System.out.println(" hay dato seleeccionado en formulaMedica" + selected);
            RequestContext context = <b>RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.execute("OprEditarFormulaDialog.show();");</b>

        }                                                                         but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
 if (selected != null) {
     System.out.println(" hay dato seleeccionado en formulaMedica" + selected);
     RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
     context.execute("PF('OprEditarFormulaDialog').show();");
 }
```

by using the Primefaces function `PF` to locate your dialog. Prerequisite: You have a `p:dialog` with `widgetvar="OprEditarFormulaDialog"`.

Comment: excellent, thank you very much. very friendly. case closed @Smutje :)